# Sql Datetimepicker format error

Tags: sql, date

```
kmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car_date", DateTimePicker1.Text);
```

`car_date` is a `date` type column and it's format is `yy-mm-dd`

but my `DateTimePicker` format is `dd.mm.yy`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Assign the `DateTimePicker.Value.Date` to your parameter - not the `.Text` string!

```
kmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car_date", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
```

The `DATE` is SQL Server (assuming you have SQL Server) has no format - it's just an 8-byte binary data.